# Ethers get contract errors as hex (unrecognized error) instead of the proper error name. Hardhat testing

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I am testing this contract, and I ran into the problem that when a function returns a revert, whether custom or not, ethers cannot decipher the error, instead it shows me that the contract could not be recognized. I did several projects with this methodology, and it had never happened to me, any clue as to what it could be?

I leave here part of the contract that I am working with and a part of the testing. (All the reverts give me error, also the ones from library contracts)

**AmmController.sol**

```
//Imports

error AMMController_LimitOfUsersExceded();

//Other errors

Contract AmmController {
// constructor
    
// other functions

function createUser(string memory _username) public {
        User storage userToCreate = users[msg.sender];
        if (userToCreate.isRegistered) {
            revert AMMController_UserAlreadyRegistered();
        }
        if (usedUsernames[_username]) {
            revert AMMController_UsernameInUse();
        }
        if (limitNumberOfUsers <= usersCount) {
            revert AMMController_LimitOfUsersExceded();
        }
        userToCreate.id = usersCount;
        userToCreate.username = _username;
        userToCreate.isRegistered = true;
        usedUsernames[_username] = true;

        usersCount++;

        ERC20 erc20StableCurrency = ERC20(stableCurrency);
        uint256 initialCurrencyForUser = initialTokensForUsers *
            initialConversionRateFromTokenToStable;

        erc20StableCurrency.transfer(msg.sender, initialCurrencyForUser);

        userStableCurrencyBalance[msg.sender] = initialCurrencyForUser;
    }
}
```

**AmmController.test.ts** (problem in the line of the `expect`)

```
// Other imports

const { assert, expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers, network, deployments } = require("hardhat");


!developmentChains.includes(network.name)
  ? describe.skip
  : describe("AMM proyect unit tests", () => {
      let ammControllerContract: any;
      let stableCurrencyAddress: string;

      beforeEach(async () => {
       
        ammControllerContract = await ethers.deployContract(
          "AMMController",
          args
        );

        await ammControllerContract.waitForDeployment();

        stableCurrencyAddress = await ammControllerContract.getStableCurrency();
      });

      describe("Contract initialization", () => {   

       //Other tests     
        
      describe("User creation", () => {

        //Other tests
       
        it("fails if the limit of users is exceded", async () => {
          const signers = await ethers.getSigners();

          for (var i = 0; i < ammCArgs.limitNumberOfUsers; i++) {
            const user = signers[i + 1];
            await ammControllerContract.connect(user).createUser(`User${i}`);

            const newUserTokenBalance =
              await ammControllerContract.getUserBalanceInStableCurrency(
                user.address
              );

            assert.equal(
              newUserTokenBalance.toString(),
              ammCArgs.initialConversionFromTokenToStable *
                ammCArgs.initialBuyOptionsOfTokensForUsers
            );
          }

          // extra invalid user

          const extraUser = signers[ammCArgs.limitNumberOfUsers + 1];

         // the problem is in this expect

          await expect(ammControllerContract
              .connect(extraUser)
              .createUser(`User${ammCArgs.limitNumberOfUsers + 1}`)
          ).to.be.rejectedWith("AMMController_LimitOfUsersExceded");
        });        
      });      
    });
```

Instead of getting the VM Exception "AMMController_LimitOfUsersExceded", I get the following:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with an unrecognized custom error (return data: 0x0a3e568a)
    at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0xcf7ed3acca5a467e9e704c703e8d87f634fb0fc9)
```